# Why yum resolve dl.google.com to an IPv6 address?

Tags: fedora, yum, chrome

I installed Google chrome browser on Fedora 18. Now when I try update softwares using `yum upgrade`, it report the following error and I can't get chrome updated.

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2404:6800:4005:c00::88: Network is unreachable"
```

It looks like dl.google.com is resolved to an IPv6 address, but I don't use IPv6, and `ping dl.google.com` returns an IPv4 address as expected.

```
# ping dl.google.com
PING dl.l.google.com (74.125.128.93) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

What's the possible reason, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure about other implementations of ping, but at least the ping from `iputils` only uses IPV4, `ping6` uses IPv6.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, yum will resolve both IPv4 & IPv6 addresses of host/domain name, see the wireshark screenshot below (I don't know python program, so network traffic capture is the only way to find out how yum resolve host name).

[image: yum resolve IP address, capture]

To resolve IPv4 address only, just add `ip_resolve=4` or `ip_resolve=ipv4` config to `yum.conf` (see `man yum.conf` for more help). For Fedora, execute the following command from terminal using root account:

```
echo "ip_resolve=4" >> /etc/yum.conf
```

To resolve IPv6 address only, change `ip_resolve=4` above to `ip_resolve=6`.

### Other programs

**`wget`** and **`curl`**

```
# To resolve IPv4 address only
wget -4
curl -4

# To resolve IPv6 address only
wget -6
curl -6
```

**`host`**

`host` also have `-4` and `-6` options, but they don't have same meaning wget & curl, they force `host` to use IPv4/IPv6 transport to query host name.

```
# To resolve IPv4 address only
host -t A

# To resolve IPv6 address only
host -t AAAA
```

Answer (score 4):

= EDIT =

It turns out `yum` *was* correctly trying both ipv4 and ipv6.  And the dns resolver in glibc correctly detected that your computer does not have a routable ipv6 address, so it preferred the ipv4 address.  However glibc still returned the ipv6 address.  It it just put the ipv6 address at the bottom of the preference list.

So `yum` tried the ipv6 address last.  Unfortunately, it seems that `yum` only showed the last error.  So `yum` only showed the error for ipv6 - which you already expected would fail! - and did not show what the error was for ipv4.

= Previous answer - which was completely wrong about the problem =

I don't know about yum.  The error sounds like it's missing an implementation of Happy Eyeballs, i.e. fallback to ipv4.  There *is* an ipv6 address...

```
$ host dl.google.com
dl.google.com is an alias for dl.l.google.com.
dl.l.google.com has address 173.194.34.132
...many randomly permuted addresses...
dl.l.google.com has address 173.194.34.137
dl.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400c:c06::5d
```

Apparently there is a workaround for when this goes wrong, which is to edit /etc/gai.conf and uncomment the line `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`.  This gives precedence to ipv4 addresses.

I think normally it should just work.  You'll have a link-local ipv6 address, but a site-local ipv4 address (or a public one without NAT).  The libc DNS resolver should then prefer ipv4 destinations.  This is specified in RFC 3484.

I wonder if this is a Teredo-style problem.  Has your router (e.g. an Apple Airport) assigned you a global IPV6 address through an unreliable tunnel?  My computer (no global ipv6) looks like this:

```
$ ip addr |grep inet6
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    inet6 fe80::215:afff:fe9f:fcd2/64 scope link
```

Comment: weird, `yum provides "/etc/gai.conf"` said it's in `glibc` package, I've already installed glibc, but I don't have `gai.conf` file under `/etc`. This's a `gai.conf` file under `/usr/share/doc/glibc-common-2.16` which comes from `glibc-common` package

Comment: my router is [TP-Link WRT841N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR841N), it only understand IPv4. `ip addr` shows inet6 entries, but they're already there before (i probably refuse to use IPv6 in my life, i don't need it).

Comment: created `/etc/gai.conf` manually with the following content: `reload yes` `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`, but i still got same error

Comment: the actual reason is our "great firewall" blocked the ip addresses which resolved by the DNS server, so yum (or the backend libcurl?) may try every IPv4 address until the last IPv6 address failed to connect. I'll choose this answer which closest to the reason. after an IP address of dl.google.com which is not blocked by GFW to /etc/hosts, 'yum update' works fine now.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研, that explanation about Yum's behaviour seems quite useful to me.  It would be nice to have it as an answer - I would upvote it :).  I expect there are more scenarios where google.com IPs would be inaccessible, beyond the content filtering applied by one particular nation.

Comment: just added my answer with wireshark screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely disable IPv6 by adding

> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

to a file in `/etc/sysctl.d`, for example `/etc/sysctl.d/disable-ipv6.conf`.

Comment: well, i added this config, restart computer, and `ip addr` does not show inet6 entries anymore, but the error still occurs.